# Can we post question answer in a form of article?

Tags: feature-request, closed-questions

Some days ago I gave answer to my own question " what is dark matter and dark energy ", it was actually a copy of an old question asked months before.

Now my concern is that I wanted to share some viewpoints related to the concerned problem and wanted to show it to every member here. But as you all know answering old questions is not useful as they won't be seen in the latest questions list. Ultimately my goal won't be achieved.

Is there any solution to so that people don't ask me to remove this question for it is a copy and still it can be seen in the active list (for some time)??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> But as you all know answering old questions is not useful as they won't be seen in the latest questions list.

Actually, answering a question bumps it up to the top of the list on the main page of the site, so people will see it.